# Android Studio (IntelliJ) ignores breakpoint in debug mode (in secondary class)

Tags: java, android, debugging, intellij-idea, android-studio

I switched from Eclipse to Android Studio (based on IntelliJ). Now, I have an app with 2 classes. When I set a breakpoint in my first class (MainActivity.java), the debugger nicely stops at that point. So I know the debugger works! However, I have a second breakpoint in my GameLayer.java class. How come my debugger ignores that breakpoint? In the debugger window it shows "The application is running" and "Frames not available".

This is in my MainActivity.java :

```
CCScene scene = GameLayer.scene(); //
CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(scene);
```

And this is in my GameLayer.java :

```
public GameLayer(){
    screenSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize();
    float generalscalefactor  = screenSize.height / 500 ;
    CCSprite background = CCSprite.sprite("bckgnd01.jpg");
    (...)
addChild(background,-5);}
```

I want to enable debugging in GameLayer.java to evaluate the variables during application run. But, as my question states, Android Studio skips those breakpoints. Please advice, thnx!

Comment: Are you using proguard?
If you use progaurd, try adding these to your proguard rules file and see if it helps:
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate

Comment: Not using proguard afaik. Will look into that.